# Configure mailgun as relayhost on top of existing postfix server already using sasl

Tags: postfix, sasl

I might be barking at the wrong tree completely here, but I'll ask anyway.

I've followed a [tutorial](https://www.exratione.com/2014/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1404-postfix-dovecot-mysql/) to setup a Mailserver on ubuntu 14.04 with postfix, dovecot and mysql.

Now I have [setup mailgun to handle the sending of emails](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html?highlight=postfix#smtp-protocol) (aka relayhost) in a secure/reliable manner.

The issue I have is the user/password of my existing email accounts have stopped working for some reason (Sending emails from CLI still works on the server) and I'm wondering if it is possible to configure the mailgun credentials in a way that does not interfere with the existing user/password.

This is a model of my master.cf before the relay

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

    # The first text sent to a connecting process.
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
    biff = no
    # appending .domain is the MUA's job.
    append_dot_mydomain = no
    readme_directory = no

    # ---------------------------------
    # SASL parameters
    # ---------------------------------

    # Use Dovecot to authenticate.
    smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
    # Referring to /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
    smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
    smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes

    # ---------------------------------
    # TLS parameters
    # ---------------------------------

    # The default snakeoil certificate. Comment if using a purchased
    # SSL certificate.
    smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    # Uncomment if using a purchased SSL certificate.
    # smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
    # smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key

    # The snakeoil self-signed certificate has no need for a CA file. But
    # if you are using your own SSL certificate, then you probably have
    # a CA certificate bundle from your provider. The path to that goes
    # here.
    # smtpd_tls_CAfile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

    # Ensure we're not using no-longer-secure protocols.
    smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3

    smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
    smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
    smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
    tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
    #smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
    #smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

    # Note that forcing use of TLS is going to cause breakage - most mail servers
    # don't offer it and so delivery will fail, both incoming and outgoing. This is
    # unfortunate given what various governmental agencies are up to these days.
    #
    # Enable (but don't force) all incoming smtp connections to use TLS.
    smtpd_tls_security_level = may
    # Enable (but don't force) all outgoing smtp connections to use TLS.
    smtp_tls_security_level = may

    # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
    # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

    # ---------------------------------
    # TLS Updates relating to Logjam SSL attacks.
    # See: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html
    # ---------------------------------

    smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-        SHA
    smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/private/dhparams.pem

    # ---------------------------------
    # SMTPD parameters
    # ---------------------------------

    # Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
    #delay_warning_time = 4h
    # will it be a permanent error or temporary
    unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
    # how long to keep message on queue before return as failed.
    # some have 3 days, I have 16 days as I am backup server for some people
    # whom go on holiday with their server switched off.
    maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
    # max and min time in seconds between retries if connection failed
    minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
    maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
    # how long to wait when servers connect before receiving rest of data
    smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
    # how many address can be used in one message.
    # effective stopper to mass spammers, accidental copy in whole address list
    # but may restrict intentional mail shots.
    smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
    # how many error before back off.
    smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
    # how many max errors before blocking it.
    smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12

    # This next set are important for determining who can send mail and relay mail
    # to other servers. It is very important to get this right - accidentally producing
    # an open relay that allows unauthenticated sending of mail is a Very Bad Thing.
    #
    # You are encouraged to read up on what exactly each of these options accomplish.

    # Requirements for the HELO statement
    smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
    # Requirements for the sender details
    smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender,         reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
    # Requirements for the connecting server
    smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl
    # Requirement for the recipient address. Note that the entry for
    # "check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023" enables Postgrey.
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient,         reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
    smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
    # This is a new option as of Postfix 2.10, and is required in addition to
    # smtpd_recipient_restrictions for things to work properly in this setup.
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient,         reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit

    # require proper helo at connections
    smtpd_helo_required = yes
    # waste spammers time before rejecting them
    smtpd_delay_reject = yes
    disable_vrfy_command = yes

    # ---------------------------------
    # General host and delivery info
    # ----------------------------------

    myhostname = mail.example.com
    myorigin = /etc/hostname
    # Some people see issues when setting mydestination explicitly to the server
    # subdomain, while leaving it empty generally doesn't hurt. So it is left empty here.
    # mydestination = mail.example.com, localhost
    mydestination =
    # If you have a separate web server that sends outgoing mail through this
    # mailserver, you may want to add its IP address to the space-delimited list in
    # mynetworks, e.g. as 10.10.10.10/32.
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    recipient_delimiter = +
    inet_interfaces = all
    mynetworks_style = host

    # This specifies where the virtual mailbox folders will be located.
    virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
    # This is for the mailbox location for each user. The domainaliases
    # map allows us to make use of Postfix Admin's domain alias feature.
    virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domainaliases_maps.cf
    # and their user id
    virtual_uid_maps = static:150
    # and group id
    virtual_gid_maps = static:8
    # This is for aliases. The domainaliases map allows us to make
    # use of Postfix Admin's domain alias feature.
    virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf
    # This is for domain lookups.
    virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf

    # ---------------------------------
    # Integration with other packages
    # ---------------------------------------

    # Tell postfix to hand off mail to the definition for dovecot in master.cf
    virtual_transport = dovecot
    dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

    # Use amavis for virus and spam scanning
    content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

    # ---------------------------------
    # Header manipulation
    # --------------------------------------

    # Getting rid of unwanted headers. See: https://posluns.com/guides/header-removal/
    header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
    # getting rid of x-original-to
    enable_original_recipient = no
```

This is what I've added to postfix's master.cf to relay through mailgun

```
relayhost = smtp.mailgun.org
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:postmaster@mydomain.com:password
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Only other thing I've changed is the certificates generated through letsencrypt.org

To summarize: Is there a way I can mantain the credentials by user and use mailgun to send mails? (Without having to create each account through the CLI)

Thanks in advanced for any help, and please let me know if anything is not clear or if more info is needed.

**UPDATE ADDED ERROR MESSAGE**:

```
Dec 14 19:24:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=190.18.x.x, lip=172.31.x.x, mpid=24023, TLS, session=<ak1PoOAmqQC+EoSW>
Dec 14 19:24:48 mail postfix/smtpd[24014]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[190.18.x.x]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Dec 14 19:24:50 mail postfix/smtpd[24014]: warning: unknown[190.18.x.x]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
Dec 14 19:24:50 mail postfix/smtpd[24014]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[190.18.x.x]
Dec 14 19:24:50 mail postfix/smtpd[24014]: disconnect from unknown[190.18.x.x]
```

Users could use imap/smtp with their generated credentials before I added the smtp relay. My best guess is postfix is trying to use that user:pass configured for the relay.

Comment: Can you pls make it a little clear what you mean by `The issue I have is the user/password of my existing email accounts have stopped working for some reason`? What error message do you get while mails sending/receiving?

Comment: @bangal added the error from the logs and a short explanation of the problem

Comment: Have you configured your client accordingly for tls after making the changes in server? What email client are you using? Check it's config.

Comment: @bangal Not sure if it is at all possible, but I want to make it so users do not have to make any changes for it to work. Something like a relayhost specific password...